# Instance of module depending on another instance of same module in Terraform

Tags: configuration, terraform

I'm trying to figure out a way to make one instance of a module depend on the successful deployment of another instance of the same module. Unfortunately, although resources support it, modules don't seem to support the explicit `depends_on` switch:

> ➜  db_terraform git:(master) ✗ terraform plan
>
> Error: module "slave": "depends_on" is not a valid argument

I have these in the root module: main.tf

```
module "master" {
  source = "./modules/database"
  cluster_role    = "master"
  ..
  server_count    = 1
}

module "slave" {
  source = "./modules/database"
  cluster_role    = "slave"
  ..
  server_count    = 3
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "db_master" {
  zone_id = "<PRIVZONE>"
  name    = "master.example.com"
  records = ["${module.master.instance_private_ip}"]
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
}
```

I want master to be deployed first. What I'm trying to do is launch two AWS instances with a database product installed. Once the master comes up, its IP will be used to create a DNS record. Once this is done, the slaves get created and will use the IP to "enlist" with the master as part of the cluster. How do I prevent the slaves from coming up concurrently with the master? I'm trying to avoid slaves failing to connect with master since the DB record may not have been created by the time the slave is ready.

I've read recommendations for using a `null_resource` in this context, but it's not clear to me how it should be used to help my problem.

Fwiw, here's the content of main.tf in the module.

```
resource "aws_instance" "database" {
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.amazonlinux_legacy.id}"
  instance_type          = "t2.xlarge"

  user_data = "${data.template_file.db_init.rendered}"
  count     = "${var.server_count}"
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I'd say the `master`, `slave` and the route53 record are all related, I would group these together in a module and call that your DB stack. Not exactly a direct solution more of a higher level 'should they live together' discussion.

Comment: I don't get it. `master` and `slave` **are** invocations of the same module. And the DNS record is needed only for the `master`.